# Share Audio file using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am not able to see any item in UIActivityViewController. I want to share Audio file to Available Sharing options in iPhone device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Review this doc, it will help you.

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.aac"];//Audio file

NSURL *fileUrl     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
NSArray *activityItems = @[fileUrl];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Sure, please check it,

Comment: you reference `UIDocumentInteractionController` but use `UIActivityViewController` in your example. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer worked for me after little bet struggle.I think there is some issue to access file path .here is modified and tested code.

```
   NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleFile"  ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
   NSArray *activityItems = @[soundFileURL];

   UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
   [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```